# Why the simulation time of a synthesized netlist depends on the clock period at which it is constrained?

Tags: verilog, synthesis, timing-analysis

I have a design which after synthesis at clock 500 picoseconds in dc_shell takes about 2 minutes to run the synthesized netlist against the testbench. The synthesized netlist worked as expected.

After that, I reduced the clock period to 400 ps and synthesized again. Timing is met again with a slack 0.43. This new netlist just took 10 seconds to complete the simulation and all the results are x.

Why is that dc_shell says timing is MET but the simulation is too fast and the results are x. Can someone please enlighten me on this?

Comment: Can you share your testbench code?

Comment: @ThePhoton Please have a look at this file.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eeMiiJeonFQ2yv7sbBkJDHk7EScVUgWt/view?usp=sharing   The image and kernel files referred are just text files containing the hexadecimal values of the image.

Comment: @ThePhoton I would like to add one more thing. MY initial design did not have input_addr_next_testing, output_addr_next_testing in I/O port declaration. Durin that time all my results were x even at 500 ps. When I added these ports to debug, the synthesized netlist started producing proper results. If I remove them, again the results are x. Basically output_addr_next_testing is input of a flip flop and input_addr is output of the ff. Similarly for output_addr_next_testing. IT is too wierd.

Comment: @ThePhoton I solved the issue...Just now had the time to post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DC_Compiler seems to have an issue in synthesizing the reset signal of the synchronous flipflops in some cases.

Just adding this compiler directive inside my flipflop module solved the issue:
//synopsys sync_set_reset "rst"

Here rst is the name of reset signal of my DFF.